# Suppress the vscodeBrowserReqId query parameter in vscode simple browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, query-string, vscode-debugger

I have a simple server application written in go and I'm using vscode as my editor.

If I run the debugger (or run the binary via `go run .`) vscode gives me a couple of options in a pop up...

> Your application running on port 8080 is available.  [See all forwarded ports]
> (command:~remote.forwardedPorts.focus)
> [Open in Browser] [Preview in Editor]

If I click the `[Preview in Editor]` button vscode launches the "Simple Browser" inside the editor and navigates to "locahost:8080" - which is really neat!

However, when I inspect the the URL in my application an additional query string is added to every request. e.g. `?vscodeBrowserReqId=<timestamp>`

Where `<timestamp>` seems to be the current unix timestamp at the time of each request.

Does anyone know if there is there a way to suppress or turn off this behaviour so that no additional query parameters are added to my requests? I really like the "Simple Browser" but the fact that it modifies queries is really annoying.

I've RTFM and looked through the settings - but I can't seem to see anything that controls (or even mentions) this behaviour. Really I would expect to be able to control/configure this in someway. Whilst I realise I can just use an external browser to avoid this entirely, I  just wondered if anyone can shed any light on this behaviour?

If I google "vscodeBrowserReqId" there are 5 results total - none of which are at all helpful!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you on this (and now this post on SO is one of the few results that come up in a search for this). It looks like this was introduced [a few years ago](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/87a3effc79a191a64854547fb6d05bd57433099f) to prevent caching, but it's bizarre to do it without any way to disable it. [Here's the location](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/90cebfaeb260263075f88dc2a8b97658942a09d7/extensions/simple-browser/preview-src/index.ts#L98) where the parameter is (always) appended.

Comment: @Sydin ah, why I didn't look at the SC myself! Thanks for the heads up - I've actually bashed together a PR to fix this by adding a `simpleBrowser.cacheBusting` setting that can be toggled to enable/disable the behaviour - much the same as the existing `simpleBrowser.focusLockIndicator` setting. Just testing it now before I submit it to vscode. Many thanks for the nudge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anyway to currently toggle this behaviour. Based on [Sydin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284142/suppress-the-vscodebrowserreqid-query-parameter-in-vscode-simple-browser#comment137448548_77284142) the code that adds the `?vscodeBrowserReqId=<timestamp>` query string to requests is [hardcoded into vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/90cebfaeb260263075f88dc2a8b97658942a09d7/extensions/simple-browser/preview-src/index.ts#L98) for all requests.

I've actually opened a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/205105) to add the ability to toggle this behaviour...and created a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/205106) to actually implement the feature.

Comment: This is awesome! I commented on the feature request — hopefully that helps it get a little more visibility. This is a weird thing to do secretly and without any way to disable.